# How to put a link on the bottom right hand side of a page

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am currently using the following code to do it.

```
<span style="position: absolute; bottom: 0pt; right: 0pt;">
  Load time: 1.1920928955078E-5 seconds</span>
```

The problem I am having is that if the page is scrollable then it is midway through the page. I am sure that there is a simple solution for this, but I can't come up with it.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: wow i edited and u removed my edit. well i guess ... nothing

Comment: Sorry I never meant that. I was removing a spelling mistake.

Comment: hey, michael, come on and register! it's easy and has great benefits.

Comment: I will definitely create an account. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need the div have position `fixed` instead of `absolute`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hqkm7/

Answer (score 2):

```
<\span style="position: absolute; bottom: 0pt; right: 0pt;">Load time: 1.1920928955078E-5 seconds<\/span>
```

should be

```
<span style="position: absolute; bottom: 0pt; right: 0pt;">Load time: 1.1920928955078E-5 seconds</span>
```

Comment: I know that. I couldn't figure out how to put my html into code tags. it kept rendering the html so I put \'s in to stop it

Answer (score 2):

you need to use position:fixed instead of position:absolute. position:absolute does not scroll with the page while positions:fixed does (by taking your span out of the flow of the page).

Comment: Clarification: An absolutely positioned element _does_ scroll with the page. An element with fixed position stays, well, fixed :-). Both are taken out of the normal document flow.